# Django Following Table

Tags: python, django, django-models

How can i alter my code so that the user logged is not able to follow themselves. I tried unique_together but could not get it to work

I will be using a button on other users profile pages to add the user to the logged in users following list in this table.

```
class FollowList(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    following = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='followers')
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you use something like intermediary model. ManyToMany in fact is a model with two ForeignKey fields: first is for your `FollowList` model and second is for linking the `User` instance. So you have an extra relation to your model. Better way:

```
class Follow(models.Model):
    follower = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='my_following_users')
    following = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='my_followers')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            ('follower', 'following'),
        )

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.follower.pk != self.following.pk:  # preventing of following themselves
            return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

# use like this
dev YourView():
    Follow.objects.create(follower=request.user, following=user)
```

UPD:
If you need to set multiple followers with once request, do something like this:

```
dev YourView():
    items = []
    for uid in ("<user ids here>"):
        items.append(Follow(follower=request.user, following__pk=uid))
    Follow.objects.bulk_create(items)
```

Comment: thanks, i will try in a bit. So i would call the yourview function from the button?

Comment: How would i modify it so that I can select multiple following users for the follow object

Comment: `YourView` is just an example, how to use `Follow` model. You should create a `Follow` instance at the any place you need.

Comment: I put a small example of your question at my post. Is it your case?

Comment: Hi, I meant, say the user visits one users page and follows them and the follow object is created. Then the user visits another users page and follows them. How can i add that to the follow object the user already has.

Comment: You don't need that. There must be a new Follow instance for a new pair of two users. For the first user, you have to create a `Follow` instance. And for the second user, you have to create another `Follow` instance. It works the same way as the M2M relations in Django.